# xslt first 10 characters of an element

Tags: xml, xslt, substring

I'm trying to create a xslt code to reduce the text of an element (Fetchdate) to its first 10 characters.
I believe that the correct function is the "substring", but unfortunately I can not make it work!

My origin xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Staff>
<File>staff.php</File>
<Fetchdate>2014-06-13 10:10:11</Fetchdate>
<IdTeam>614</IdTeam>
<StaffMechanicians>20</StaffMechanicians>
<StaffTechnics>6</StaffTechnics>
<StaffPR>12</StaffPR>
<StaffObservers>2</StaffObservers>
<StaffFitnessCoaches>4</StaffFitnessCoaches>
<StaffRepairman>10</StaffRepairman>
<StaffTeamSpirit>20</StaffTeamSpirit>
</Staff>
```

Expected xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Staff>
<File>staff.php</File>
<Fetchdate>2014-06-13</Fetchdate>
<IdTeam>614</IdTeam>
<StaffMechanicians>20</StaffMechanicians>
<StaffTechnics>6</StaffTechnics>
<StaffPR>12</StaffPR>
<StaffObservers>2</StaffObservers>
<StaffFitnessCoaches>4</StaffFitnessCoaches>
<StaffRepairman>10</StaffRepairman>
<StaffTeamSpirit>20</StaffTeamSpirit>
</Staff>
```

Who can help me to generate the xslt code?
thanks.

Comment: "I cannot make it work" - what have you tried so far, what output did it produce and how is that different from the output you wanted?  On SO we're happy to help you debug _your_ code, but it's not our job to write it all for you.

Answer (score 4):

The expression should be:

```
substring(/Staff/Fetchdate, 1, 10)
```

You have to keep in mind, that indizes in Xpath start with 1 not 0.

Putting it into a template match:

```
<xsl:template match="Staff/Fetchdate">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 10)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Another possibility in this case would be `substring-before()`

```
<xsl:template match="Staff/Fetchdate">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but there is a problem.
The output is:
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    circuito.php
    2014-06-13
    614
    614
    614
    Olimpia Autodromo
    4458
    1500 
    500
    250
    89
    86
    3675
    500
    100
    0
    0 
    0
    1526
    Noldor
    485570
    Llazar Abdihoxha
    82714
    2014-02-08 13:00:03
    1


I must edit only <Fetchdate>2014-06-13 10:10:11</Fetchdate> in <Fetchdate>2014-06-13</Fetchdate>. Leaving the rest of the xml file unchanged.

Comment: sorry, I have made ​​an error in the output. the correct is:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
staff.php
2014-06-13
614
20
6
12
2
4
10
20

 I must edit only <Fetchdate>2014-06-13 10:10:11</Fetchdate> in <Fetchdate>2014-06-13</Fetchdate>. Leaving the rest of the xml file unchanged.

Comment: The default handling for unknown elements in xslt is to remove them. You will have to write a generic match to copy them.